# Push notification doesn't show or gets disappeared right away [CodenameOne]

Tags: android, push-notification, codenameone

I have two Android devices, Android 7.0 and Android 8.1.0 and am trying to use CodenameOne to send push notifications to them.
When I send push notifications (type 99) it displays on the Android 8 device properly.
However, the Android 7.0 device seem to collect all push notifications in tray and show only briefly - for less than a second or not to show it at all. I can see that the notification was received only if the device is sleeping (the screen is black). But after I unlock the phone, the notifications are not shown anymore.

Also, another problem that might be related: in my `push(String value)` method I implemented ToastBar with notification body message in case if display is ***not*** minimized. So after I receive push notification in Android 7 device and then open the app (even if it was minimized when the push was received), I can see ToastBar (Or many of them, if there were few pushes. It's not suppose to happen).

Android logs for receiving push seem to be fine in both versions. They look like this:

> `2021-03-08 12:14:52.308 16422-21684/com.company.app I/System.out: Message received {messageType=3, category=reminder, message=Reminder !;{'id':'251'} }`
>
> `2021-03-08 12:14:52.308 16422-21684/com.company.app I/System.out: Push message received: Reminder !;{'id':'251'}`
>
> `2021-03-08 12:14:52.308 16422-21684/com.company.app I/System.out: Push type: 3`
>
> `2021-03-08 12:14:52.30816422-21684/com.company.app I/System.out: Is running: false`

However, I noticed that Android 7.0 Phone also has this:

> `2021-03-08 11:46:07.686 1548-1548/? V/NotificationService: pkg=com.company.app canInterrupt=false intercept=true`

Comment: `push(String)` will always be called (even for background push messages). You need to explicitly protect against showing messages you don't want shown. When you say show it briefly you mean remove from the tray? The native Android show? Is that different from the behavior of other apps e.g. gmail?

Comment: The notification is shown in tray briefly, for less than a second, and then disappears. Sometimes though it doesn't show there at all. Yes, I believe it's a native Android show tray. Notifications are implemented using `push()` of `com.codename1.push`. It happens only for this app, all other notifications work fine.

Comment: Also, I just noticed. When the app is killed, the 7.0 device receives and displays notification properly. It shows briefly only when the app is running in background.

Comment: I think you mean when the app is in the foreground? When the app is running we remove push notifications from the tray to make the behavior consistent with iOS which behaves in that way. Our assumption is that the app UI is in the foreground and as such you can show the UI notification within the app.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog foreground you mean when the app is displayed on the screen? No, the app is not displayed, it's just running on the background and can be found in the list of currently running applications (like PlayStore app on this screenshot https://imgur.com/OnIHoOE). 
So on my different device even though the app is listed as running, I receive push. But not on this Android 7.0.

Comment: It might be one of the edge cases for push on Android. This is pretty hard to debug normally. If you connect the device to a cable then send a push do you see anything printed in the logcat?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I updated the original post with logs. Also, I noticed that push type 1 notifications have the same problem.

Comment: I understand there are no exceptions or anything suspicious in the console of the problematic device? If you inspect the app it looks like it has all the permissions set correctly right? You don't have any special 3rd party tool installed that might cause a problem with push messages?

Comment: Logs don't show anything suspicious except that `V/NotificationService: pkg=com.company.app canInterrupt=false intercept=true`, in App Permission settings everything is allowed, in App notifications settings "Do Not Disturb" is overridden. No 3rd party tools are installed and all other app notifications work fine. Also I know that I do receive the push. It just doesn't appear in front of foreground when push is received (or it appears for less than a second) and doesn't stay displayed in the notification drawer.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I might have resolved this issue. But I have not tested the app on other devices yet, only Android 7.0. Also I don't understand why it was causing the bug. 
So I removed `android.background_push_handling=true` build hint and now notifications are displayed properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug resolved my removing `android.background_push_handling=true` from build hints in `codenameone_settings.properties`